# Can't seem to get description file to appear using help function/operator in R

Tags: r, package

I am creating an R package and I have the description file with necessary information needed. Once I have everything built and installed from RStudio and I load in my package, I can't use the "?" operator to get documentation of the package.

I have tried multiple times to document using devtools::document() in case it wasn't documenting, however that does not seem to work. I know that it's supposed to document the help files for the functions but I thought that might work.

Comment: Is your code on GitHub or something? It’s impossible to say what’s going on with out being able to see any code. Are you exporting your functions?

Comment: Hi, I was able to figure it out. I ended up using `usethis::use_package_doc()` which is what I needed. Essentially, I wanted a help file for the package name.